# ASP Text box ID assignment using a for loop.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, textbox

I am a noob and i've been trying to figure out how we may assign an ID to `asp:TextBox` tags on creation in ASP.NET using c#.

**Example:**

I need to create a thread that may have multiple textboxes.

When a user clicks on a button, a text box must be generated with an `ID` say, `txt01`. On being clicked the second time, the `ID` of the generated text box must be `txt02` and so on..depending on the number of clicks.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: u want to dynamically create textbox and assign ids...is that what u wanna do??

Answer (score 0):

Remember last ID in some variable, for example `int lastID`, then in button's onClick method when creating the new TextBox assign its `ID="txt"+lastID;`.

You have to persist the lastID during page postbacks, you can store it in a `ViewState`.

Answer (score 0):

Take and `placeholder` in your aspx page: eg: `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="pholder" />`

and in code behind:

```
TextBox txtMyText = new TextBox();
tb1.ID = YourDynamicId;
pholder.Controls.Add(txtMyText);
```

You can save current id in ViewState and get the same id and assign incremented id to your dynamic textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
        int i = 1;
        if (ViewState["i"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["i"] = i;
        }
        else
            i = (int)ViewState["i"];
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            TextBox TextBox = new TextBox();
            TextBox.ID = "TextBox" + j.ToString();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(TextBox);
        }
        ViewState["i"] = i + 1;
```

add this on your .aspx page

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Hope This help.

Answer (score 0):

store the id in a `ViewState` something like this
First initialise a count variable similiar to this.
in your `class` write this

```
protected int replyCount     //declare the variable
{
    get { return (int)ViewState["replyCount"]; }
    set { ViewState["replyCount"] = value; }
}
```

In your page Load write this to initialise the replyCount if its not a postback;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!page.IsPostBack)
   {
     replyCount = 0;           //initialise the variable
   }
}
```

then  while creating dynamic textboxes

```
protected void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox tb = new TextBox();
   tb.id = "tb" + replycount;   //use the variable
   replycount++;                 // and after using increment it.
   form.controls.add(tb);        // assuming your form name is "form"
}
```

Thats it you should do.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for -

You will notice that I have used `Page_Init` because if you create/add the controls in `Page_Load` then `FindControl` will return null in `PostBack`. And also any data you entered in the dynamically added controls will not persist during Postbacks.

But `Page_Init` is called before `ViewState` or `PostBack` data is loaded. Therefore, you can not use `ViewState` or any other controls to keep the control count. So I have used `Session` to keep the count.

Try it out and let me know what you think.

### ASPX Page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRead" runat="server" Text="Read" OnClick="btnRead_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected int NumberOfControls
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(Session["noCon"]); }
    set { Session["noCon"] = value.ToString(); }
}

private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        //Initiate the counter of dynamically added controls
        this.NumberOfControls = 0;
    else
        //Controls must be repeatedly be created on postback
        this.createControls();
}
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
    tbx.ID = "txtData"+NumberOfControls;
    NumberOfControls++;

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbx);
}
protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = this.NumberOfControls;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tx = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtData" + i.ToString());
        //Add the Controls to the container of your choice
        Label1.Text += tx.Text + ",";
    }
}

private void createControls()
{
    int count = this.NumberOfControls;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tx = new TextBox();
        tx.ID = "txtData" + i.ToString();
        //Add the Controls to the container of your choice
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tx);
    }
}
```